# WCF OData patching an entity set

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

Is it possible in update multiple entites based on a filter query in a batch request?

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve, say I want to update all product categories from foo to bar in one request to an OData endpoint, is there something like this that would work:

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_fa7b-4aa9-a01f

GET /api/products?$filter=category eq 'foo' HTTP/1.1
Accept:application/json
Content-ID: 1

--changeset_fa7b-4aa9-a01f
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

PATCH $1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

{"category":"bar"}

--changeset_fa7b-4aa9-a01f--

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no. There's **no support** for that in the protocol. And even if you remove the filtering from the question, trying to update all entities in the entity set so that they will have a same new value, the answer is still no.

You could probably do this yourself. Like,

```
Get /service.svc/MyEntitySet
```

and for every entity you get back, send a `PATCH` to **update it individually**.

In addition, if this kind of operation is going to be done frequently, the service author could **write a specific service operation or action to do this on the server side**. For example, write something called `"ClearAllNames"`, and a user could invoke that, and the server would go through every entity and clear its name field.